# when i run my app in physical device this error comes please suggest

Tags: flutter

Launching lib\main.dart on CMA LX2 in debug mode...
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/image_provider.dart:812:92: Error: Couldn't find constructor 'network_image.NetworkImage'.
const factory NetworkImage(String url, { double scale, Map<String, String>? headers }) = network_image.NetworkImage;
^

/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/image_provider.dart:812:92: Error: Redirection constructor target not found: 'network_image.NetworkImage'
const factory NetworkImage(String url, { double scale, Map<String, String>? headers }) = network_image.NetworkImage;
^

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1156
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 17s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)

Comment: You should check for any compile time error (Syntax error)

Comment: the issue seems to be caused by the NetworkImage widget. Does this error not occur on an emulator? can you also provide your flutter version